# Как сделать плавный поворот объекта?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

Неважно на каком языке я делаю программу, у меня есть угол мыши относительно середины экрана, и объект по середине экрана, если угол объекта указывать как угол мыши то он будет некрасиво передвигаться (за мышью).
Сейчас мой код такой:

`if mouse_angle > object_angle: object_angle += 1`

`elif mouse_angle < object_angle:    object_angle -= 1`
`object_angle %= 360`

Но когда значение меньше 0, то автоматически mouse_angle перескакивает на 360, и объект получается обратно идёт, так как mouse_angle > object_angle

Подскажите пожалуйста если знаете как это сделать ( if object_angle < 1: object_angle = 360.  я пробовал но не Помогло)

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599851/how-do-i-make-smooth-movement-rotation-in-pygame#:~:text=The%20issue%20is%20caused%20by%20the%20code%20which%20rotates%20the%20sprite.